# Not getting any incoming call notification, nor is the dongle answering up the call

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to get asterisk to configure and answer incoming call. This is just the first step towards the development. Once the modem picks up the call I will start developing the dial plan. Please review my conf files

dongle.conf

```
[general]
interval=15
[defaults]
context=dongle-incoming         
group=0                         
rxgain=0                        
txgain=0                        
autodeletesms=yes               
resetdongle=yes                 
u2diag=-1                       
usecallingpres=yes              
callingpres=allowed_passed_screen 
disablesms=no                   
language=en                     
mindtmfgap=45                   
mindtmfduration=80              
mindtmfinterval=200             
callwaiting=auto                
disable=no                      
exten=+1234567890               
dtmf=relax unaltered diaplan
[dongle0]
audio=/dev/ttyUSB1             
data=/dev/ttyUSB0               
imei=<valid>
imsi=<valid>
```

extensions.conf

```
[general]
static = yes
writeprotect = no
clearglobalvars = no
[globals]
CONSOLE = Console/dsp  ; Console interface for demo
;CONSOLE=DAHDI/1
;CONSOLE=Phone/phone0
IAXINFO = guest  ; IAXtel username/password
;IAXINFO=myuser:mypass
TRUNK = DAHDI/G2  ; Trunk interface
TRUNKMSD = 1  ; MSD digits to strip (usually 1 or 0)
FEATURES = 
DIALOPTIONS = 
RINGTIME = 20
FOLLOWMEOPTIONS = 
PAGING_HEADER = Intercom

[dongle-incoming]
exten => sms,1,Verbose(Incoming SMS from ${CALLERID(num)} ${SMS})
exten => sms,n,System(echo '${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} - ${DONGLE} - ${CALLERID(num)}: ${SMS}' >> /var/log/asterisk/sms.txt)
exten => sms,n,Hangup()

exten => ussd,1,Verbose(Incoming USSD: ${USSD})
exten => ussd,n,System(echo '${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} - ${DONGLE}: ${USSD}' >> /var/log/asterisk/ussd.txt)
exten => ussd,n,Hangup()

exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/100,,)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

Some debugging steps

- dongle show device state returns

-------------- Status -------------

```
  Device                  : dongle0
  State                   : Free
  Audio                   : /dev/ttyUSB1
  Data                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
  Voice                   : Yes
  SMS                     : Yes
  Manufacturer            : huawei
  Model                   : E303D
  Firmware                : 21.157.72.00.356
  IMEI                    : <valid>
  IMSI                    : <valid>
  GSM Registration Status : Registered, home network
  RSSI                    : 18, -114 dBm
  Mode                    : No Service
  Submode                 : No service
  Provider Name           : IDEA
  Location area code      : "A03D"
  Cell ID                 : "B96B"
  Subscriber Number       : Unknown
  SMS Service Center      : <valid>
  Use UCS-2 encoding      : Yes
  USSD use 7 bit encoding : No
  USSD use UCS-2 decoding : Yes
  Tasks in queue          : 0
  Commands in queue       : 0
  Call Waiting            : Disabled
  Current device state    : start
  Desired device state    : start
  When change state       : now
  Calls/Channels          : 0
    Active                : 0
    Held                  : 0
    Dialing               : 0
    Alerting              : 0
    Incoming              : 0
    Waiting               : 0
    Releasing             : 0
    Initializing          : 0
```

- the status does not change when I make incoming calls. Ideally 'Incoming' should increase. It does not.
- `dongle sms dongle0 +911234567890 hi`, the sms is sent and it works
- `dongle cmd dongle0  dongle cmd dongle0 ATD+91123456789T;`, this works, the outbound call happens
- `dongle cmd dongle0 ATSO=1;` goes through, but calls are still not picked up at all. Ideally should pickup after 1 ring.

What am I missing in the config ? I know its something small and silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of trial and error. I finally fixed the issue. The dongle.conf had to be changed to `audio=ttyUSB1` and `data=ttyUSB2`. This only got to the stage of the incoming call notification coming in. From then on, the dongle.conf needs one more change. The context needs to point to your helloworld in extension.conf. So I created a `context=dongle-incoming`. In the extensions.conf I put in

```
[dongle-incoming]
exten => s,1,Answer(500)
exten => s,n,SayPhonetic(hello to taxeeta)
```

Also in extensions.conf I put `include=>dongle-incoming` and removed `include=>default`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, caused by the enabled [extended CRC](https://www.activexperts.com/sms-component/at/commands/?at=%2BCRC) and [missing support](https://github.com/wdoekes/asterisk-chan-dongle/issues/82) for it in the asterisk-chan-dongle that I'm using.

Resolved it by switching off extended CRC with the following command:

```
$ dongle cmd dongle0 AT+CRC=0
```